# ModelState.AddModelError why is there no ModelState.AddModelSuccess?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, modelstate

ModelState is a dictionary object that contains the state of the model and of model-building validation.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MyKey", "My Error Message");
```

`AddModelError()` which adds the specified error messages to the errors collection of model state dictionary that is linked with the specified key (MyKey).

Why there is no `ModelState.AddModelSucces("MyKey", "My Error Message")`? Can anybody tell how to show success messages in View.

```
ModelState.AddModelSucces("MyKey", "My Error Message") ???
```

Comment: It is by design,You would only add error messages to a model state. If you want success message just use an alternative view model or a viewbag to do so.

Comment: @David `ModelState.IsValid` represents Boolean value i want to know how to add success messages like `ModelState.AddModelSuccess` unfortunately this method was not available ?

Comment: Use something like TempData? That's a Dictionary<string, object> collection.

Comment: @David +1 I can use as alternate way by using `TempData["key"]`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a HTML helper extension method following the same lines as Html.ValidationMessageFor.

Below is an example of what I quickly knocked up but you could extend it further. Have a look at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValidationExtensions.cs to get more ideas.

This outputs a `span` tag with css class `field-validation-valid`.

```
<span class="field-validation-valid">My success message</span>
```

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationSuccessMessageFor(m => m.MyProperty, "My success message")
```

**Extension Method**

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSuccessMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return ValidationSuccessMessageFor(htmlHelper, expression, null, new RouteValueDictionary());
}

public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSuccessMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string validationMessage)
{
    return ValidationSuccessMessageFor(htmlHelper, expression, validationMessage, new RouteValueDictionary());
}

public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSuccessMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string validationMessage, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return ValidationSuccessMessageFor(htmlHelper, expression, validationMessage, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}

public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSuccessMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string validationMessage, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    return ValidationMessageHelper(htmlHelper, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData), ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), validationMessage, htmlAttributes);
}

private static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string expression, string validationMessage, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    var modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
        FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext : null;

    if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName) && formContext == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];

    if (modelState == null || (modelState != null && (modelState.Errors == null || modelState.Errors.Count > 0)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var builder = new TagBuilder("span");
    builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    builder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageValidCssClassName);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
    {
        builder.SetInnerText(validationMessage);
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```